# GhostDoc VisualStudio extension Load exception

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, ghostdoc

I've formatted my harddrive to reinstall **Windows 8 x64**.

After installing `VisualStudio 2013` and then [**GhostDoc extension**](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx), in the moment that I try to run the VS IDE (an VB/C# project of any kind), it throws an exception related to `GhostDoc` that I would like to solve:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The English translation of the error message above (that is in Spanish) is this:

> Exception Source: mscorlib
>
> Exception Type: System.IO.FileLoadException
>
> Exception Message: Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131401)

I never had this problem until now.

The exception happens in GhostDoc version **4.8** and **4.9**, the error seems not to be critical 'cause I'm still able to use GhostDoc after accepting the ErrorDialog, but anyways I would like to solve this 'cause I have other kind of problems, I need to install 3rd party controls/extensions silently and if I run the IDE and I get this error then just I can't install nothing 'cause it stops the execution of the IDE, so at the moment what I've did to avoid this error is editing the `LoadBehavior` property in the `GhostDocPro.AddIn` XML file, to disable the automatic loading of the extension:

```
<LoadBehavior>0</LoadBehavior>
```

Then now every time that I want to use GhostDoc I need to load it manually (see first image above), and of course I'm having the same exception, I need to solve this bug.

This is the Exception:

> Detailed error information follows: Date and Time: 26/03/2014 11:55:17
>   IP Address: {0} OS Platform: Win32NT Processor: AMD64 OS version:
>   6.2.9200.0 Current user role:  Administrator; User;
>
> Allocated Memory: 51 Mb Available Physical Memory: 4096 Mb Available
>   Virtual Memory: 3255 Mb Total Physical Memory: 4096 Mb Total Virtual
>   Memory: 4096 Mb Percentage of physical memory In use: 44 %
>
> Application Domain: DefaultDomain Product Version: 4.9.14064.0
>   Assembly Codebase: file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual
>   Studio
>   12.0/Common7/IDE/Extensions/SubMain/GhostDoc/1.0/SubMain.GhostDoc.Core.DLL
>   Assembly Version: 2.2.0.0 Assembly Build Date: 05/03/2014 1:39:38
>   Assembly Full Name: SubMain.GhostDoc.Core, Version=2.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=94c677ee32cc1929
>
> Exception Source: mscorlib Exception Type: System.IO.FileLoadException
>   Exception Message: Si se carga este ensamblado, se generará un
>   conjunto de permisos diferente de otras instancias. (Excepción de
>   HRESULT: 0x80131401) Exception Target Site: CreateInstance
>
> ---- Stack Trace ----  System.AppDomain.nCreateDomain(friendlyName As String, setup As AppDomainSetup, providedSecurityInfo As Evidence,
>   creatorsSecurityInfo As Evidence, parentSecurityDescriptor As IntPtr) 
>   SubMain.GhostDoc.Core.DLL: N 00000 
>   System.AppDomainManager.CreateDomainHelper(friendlyName As String,
>   securityInfo As Evidence, appDomainInfo As AppDomainSetup) 
>   SubMain.GhostDoc.Core.DLL: N 00283 
>   System.AppDomainManager.CreateDomain(friendlyName As String,
>   securityInfo As Evidence, appDomainInfo As AppDomainSetup) 
>   SubMain.GhostDoc.Core.DLL: N 00014 
>   System.AppDomain.InternalCreateDomain(friendlyName As String,
>   securityInfo As Evidence, info As AppDomainSetup) 
>   SubMain.GhostDoc.Core.DLL: N 10814956 
>   System.AppDomain.CreateDomain(friendlyName As String, securityInfo As
>   Evidence, info As AppDomainSetup)  SubMain.GhostDoc.Core.DLL: N 00039 
>   A.c112f74fdd78a5b016f03ca0edba39a26.c9495450a44f85fef6ae7cb241984a67a(
>   As String,  As Evidence,  As AppDomainSetup) 
>   SubMain.GhostDoc.Core.DLL: N 00023 
>   SubMain.Core.Utils.RemoteLoader.cc3c5bc8929eea714ac8c7a330d95ac0b( As
>   String)  SubMain.GhostDoc.Core.DLL: N 00142
>
> Loaded assemblies:    Assembly Name: mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089  Assembly Location:
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll
>
> More info ...

( The full stack trace is [**here**](http://pastebin.com/fE4v8zgc) )

Any ideas about the `System.IO.FileLoadException` exception that I'm facing?

---

PS: If someone is thinking why I'm posting this issue here in **StackOverflow** instead of contacting to GhostDoc team, well I've sent the bug to GhostDoc Developers but I remember that they didn't wanted to helped me in other StackOverFlow post (that was not related to any bug, was a very simple question about how to uninstall their product in X circunstances), so I really don't expect any help from GhostDoc team to solve this in StackOverflow and maybe (only maybe) I could have more choices to solve this issue with the help of other users that maybe has the same issue.

Comment: Spanish exception message in english: If you load this assembly, it will generate a different set of permissions for other instances.

Comment: Have you tried running vs2013 as administrator?

Comment: @Paul Zahra Yes I'm already the only Admin account on my PC, I've tried now to run the Devenv.exe as Administrator and the problem persists. thanks for comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

To add an assembly to the fully trusted assembly list ([taken from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eccaxwce%28v=vs.90%29.aspx))

- In the .NET Framework 1.0 and 1.1, at the command line, type
  %Systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Mscorcfg.msc. In
  the .NET Framework 2.0, start the SDK Command Prompt and type
  mscorcfg.msc.
- The user interface for the tool is displayed.
- Expand the Runtime Security Policy node.
- Expand the node for the policy level you want to add the new assembly to.
- Right-click Policy Assemblies and choose Add.
- Select the assembly name from the list that appears. These are the assemblies that are in the global assembly cache.
- Click Select.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but in the folders (and subfolders) of `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` and/or `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64` I have any `Mscorcfg.msc` file to run, I've ran an explorer searcher in my PC but the file does not exists anywhere. Maybe the same could be done using other way in commandline?

Comment: Oh, I'm seeing this now http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/771ss30w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx but I'm not sure which assembly I need to add (DevEnv.exe, GhostDoc.core.dll, other?) I'm trying things now

Comment: Using this simple Batch command `For %a in ("*.dll") Do (Start /W "" "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\caspol.exe" -y -user -addfulltrust "%a")` to add all the .NET Assemblies to the Security Policy inside these folders: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\SubMain\GhostDoc\1.0` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\GhostDoc` did not solved the exception

Comment: hmm... I take it you are running a 32 bit machine? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  (For example, the location is %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.030319\caspol.exe for the .NET Framework 4 on a 64-bit system.) Multiple versions of the tool might be installed if your computer is running multiple versions of the .NET Framework side by side.

Comment: Also note the caution section for addfulltrust... this was a bit of a long shot... especially as you seem to be the only one experiencing this issue - according to google at least ;)

Comment: I've clarified that I'm running Windows 8 x64, but the SO has installed by default both folders in "Framework" and "Framework64", from versions 1.0 to 4.0, I didn't tried all caspol's executables from those folders, I'm gonna try it now, thanks